# Cannot use pandas.Series.replace method to replace the string "NaT" with None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I can't replace the 'NaT' string in my column of type object.

Code

```
print(d['cancellation_month'].dtype)
d['cancellation_month'] = d['cancellation_month'].replace('NaT', None)
print((d['cancellation_month'] == 'NaT').sum())

d.loc[d.cancellation_month == 'NaT', 'cancellation_month'] = None
print((d['cancellation_month'] == 'NaT').sum())
```

Output:

```
object
3
0
```

Comment: fillna() also works with NaT you should try

Comment: Are you sure it’s the string ‘NaT’ and not `pd.NaT` the missing Datetime object?

Comment: the problem is really the value `None` because it is the value par default and kind of ignore it, you can do it like this `d['cancellation_month'].replace(['NaT'],[ None])` or this `d['cancellation_month'].replace({'NaT': None})`. that's said, if the rest of the values in the columns are datetime like object, maybe you can consider to do `pd.to_datetime(d['cancellation_month'])` to convert directly to datetime column and the string `'NaT'` are convert to `pd.NaT`

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can't use `replace` with `value=None`

If the `value` is `None` and `to_replace` is not a dictionary, the value is set to `to_replace` parameter. So, `NaT` will be replaced by `Nat`.

Check the [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L6472-L6476)

```
        if value is None:
            # passing a single value that is scalar like
            # when value is None (GH5319), for compat
            if not is_dict_like(to_replace) and not is_dict_like(regex):
                to_replace = [to_replace]
```